# How to assign IF(INDEX(MATCH formula using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert some values and formulas using a WITH block.

The simple formulas are being assigned, but when it gets to the first multiple formula (the one in .Range("J2") it throws

> 1004 application-defined or object-defined error

I'm assuming there's something wrong with my syntax. I remember something from years ago about having to use ampersands to split the formula in the code, but not sure.

I've looked at solutions here and some other sites too, but none of them seem similar enough to answer my question.

```
With MainPg
    lstrw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    '.Range("A1") = "article"
    .Range("B1") = "season"
    .Range("C1") = "bu name"
    .Range("D1") = "dept"
    .Range("E1") = "range name"
    .Range("F1") = "item name"
    .Range("G1") = "stroke"
    .Range("H1") = "colour"
    .Range("I1") = "stroke name"
    .Range("J1") = "newness"
    .Range("K1") = "equivalent stroke/colour"
    .Range("L1") = "pre-lockdown category"
    .Range("M1") = "post-lockdown category"
    .Range("B2").Formula = "='Upload'!A2"
    .Range("C2").Formula = "='Upload'!F2"
    .Range("D2").Formula = "='Upload'!G2"
    .Range("E2").Formula = "='Upload'!K2"
    .Range("F2").Formula = "='Upload'!L2"
    .Range("G2").Formula = "='Upload'!H2"
    .Range("H2").Formula = "='Upload'!J2"
    .Range("I2").Formula = "='Upload'!M2"
    .Range("J2").Formula = "=IF(INDEX('Upload'!C:C," & "MATCH([@article],'Upload'!E:E,0))=43597,""Y"",""N"")"
    .Range("L2").Formula = "=IF(LEN([@[Equivalent Stroke/Colour]])<1,INDEX('Upload'!O:O,MATCH([@article],'Upload'!E:E,0)),INDEX('LastYear'!J:J,MATCH([@[Equivalent Stroke/Colour]],'LastYear'!I:I,0)))"
    .Range("M2").Formula = "=IF([@[pre lockdown category]]=""UNCATEGORISED"",""REGULAR"",[@[pre lockdown category]])"
    .Range("B2:M2").Copy
    .Range("B3:M" & lstrw).PasteSpecial.xlPasteFormulas
    Set rng1 = Range("A1:M" & lstrw)
    Set table1 = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng1, , xlYes)
    table1.TableStyle = "TableStylemedium13"
End With
```

Comment: What is `@article`? and what's it's value?

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the `'.Range("A1") = "article"` line?

Comment: Thanks to your comments I've just realised my error. I'm writing this macro to construct copies of a file that I made without VBA. I think it's not working because I've tried to insert the formula before formatting as a table. What an idiot! I'll try replacing @article with A2. Thanks for giving me the nudge I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look:

```
Sub t2est()

    Dim article As String

    article = "Test"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload")

        .Range("J2").Formula = "=IF(INDEX('Upload'!C:C,MATCH(" & """" & article & """" & ",'Upload'!E:E,0))=43597,""Y"",""N"")"

    End With

End Sub
```

**Upload Sheet:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think my error is as per my comment above, but this also works